Compare 2 Lists/Array in Scala Spark
I have 2 lists:
# time taken 
x1 = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

# time alloted 
y1 = List(15, 30)

here are some more examples
+-------------------+----------------------+----------+
|       time_taken  |       time_alloted   | result   |
+-------------------+----------------------+----------+
|         160-80-40 |            [20,40,80]|        80|
|            520-90 |           [45,90,130]|       130|
|    60-120-240-480 |              [30,120]|       120|
| 10-10-10-20-20-30 |               [12,30]|        12|
| 10-20-30-40-50-60 |               [12,30]|        30|
| 45-40-40-40-40-40 |           [45,90,130]|        45|
+-------------------+----------------------+----------+

I need to compare the seconds in time_taken column and time_alloted column according to the following rules:

if Elements in time_taken should be completely divisible by elements in time_alloted (traverse from max to min), assign the max time
Eg : result 80 (3 units of 80 and 1 unit of 40, consider 80)
if an element in time_taken > max element in time_alloted, multiply elements in time_alloted with *2, *3, *4 ... till we get one complete unit after division (130 * 5 = 520)
if elements are not completely divisible, check which element leave less remainder

Basically if there is a ListA with 1...n elements and another ListB with 1...m element
I want to compate each element form ListA with all elements in ListB to get the appropriate value
Edit : I am calculating using SQL, I am looking for solution using data structures or higer order function
from both Lists I am calculating size, max, min, storing each element in separate column time_taken cols : tim_size, tim_max, tim_min, dt1, dt2, dt3
time_alloted cols : alt_size, alt_max_sec, alt_min_sec, t1, t2, t3
    when tim_size ==1 and alt_size == 1 then alt_max_sec 
    when mod(tim_min, alt_max_sec) == 0 then alt_max_sec 
    when tim_size ==1 and alt_size == 2 and MOD(tim_max, alt_max_sec) == 0 then alt_max_sec
    when tim_size ==1 and alt_size == 2 and MOD(tim_max, alt_min_sec) == 0 then alt_min_sec
    when tim_size ==1 and alt_size == 3 and MOD (tim_max, alt_max_sec) == 0 then alt_max_sec
    when tim_size ==1 and alt_size == 3 and MOD (tim_max, t2) == 0 then t2
    when tim_size ==1 and alt_size == 3 and MOD (tim_max, alt_min_sec) == 0 then alt_min_sec
    when tim_size ==2 and alt_size == 1 then alt_max_sec
    when tim_size ==2 and alt_size == 2 and MOD(tim_max, alt_max_sec) == 0 and MOD(tim_min, alt_max_sec) == 0 then alt_max_sec
    when tim_size ==2 and alt_size == 2 and MOD(tim_max, alt_min_sec) == 0 and MOD(tim_min, alt_min_sec) == 0 then alt_min_sec
    when tim_size ==2 and alt_size == 2 and MOD(tim_min, alt_min_sec) == 0 then alt_min_sec
    when tim_size ==2 and alt_size == 3 and MOD(tim_max, alt_max_sec) == 0 and MOD(tim_min, alt_max_sec) == 0 then alt_max_sec
    when tim_size ==2 and alt_size == 3 and MOD(tim_max, t2) == 0 and MOD(tim_min, t2) == 0 then t2
    when tim_size ==2 and alt_size == 3 and MOD(tim_max, alt_max_sec) == 0 and MOD(tim_min, t2) == 0 and ((tim_max/alt_max_sec) > (tim_min/t2)) THEN alt_max_sec
    WHEN tim_size ==2 and alt_size == 3 and (tim_max/t2) == 1 and (tim_min/t1) == 1 then alt_min_sec
    WHEN tim_size ==3 and alt_size == 3 and mod(tim_max, alt_max_sec) == 0 and mod(dt2, alt_max_sec) == 0 then alt_max_sec
    WHEN tim_size ==3 and alt_size == 3 and mod(tim_max, alt_max_sec) == 0 and mod(dt2, alt_max_sec) == 0 then alt_max_sec
    WHEN tim_size ==3 and alt_size == 2 and MOD(tim_max, alt_max_sec) == 0 and mod(dt2, alt_max_sec) == 0 then alt_max_sec
    when alt_size == 3 and mod(tim_min, t2) == 0 then t2
else 'TBC' end as result ```


is the time_taken column supposed to be an ArrayType like time_allotted?

yes both Columns are Array type array

please show what you have tried to do

So... what exactly is the problem which you faced ?

added that part in main question

how are dt1-dt3 and t1-t3 calculated?  Your examples show multiple values but only 3 as a max size in the sql.  Are you asking the question because the sql approach shown isn't scaling to more entries?

yes, in SQL way I need to add more and more cases as size of list increases
I am looking if there is simpler way
dt1-dt3 are each element of an array of size 3 same goes with t1, t2, t3
